# Timing CUDA kernels which should be executed more than 1 time

Tags: cuda

I want to count the time of kernel which should be runned for more than 1 times,the data to be processed is different for each kernel being executed.My code is below, for the time of cudaMemcpy should not be counted.

```
1 cudaEvent_t start;
2 error = cudaEventCreate(&start);
3 cudaEvent_t stop;
4 error = cudaEventCreate(&stop);
6 float msecTotal = 0.0f;
7 int nIter = 300;
8 for (int j = 0; j < nIter; j++)
9 {            
10      cudaMemcpy(...);
        // Record the start event
11      error = cudaEventRecord(start, NULL);
12      matrixMulCUDA1<<< grid, threads >>>(...);
       // Record the stop event
13      error = cudaEventRecord(stop, NULL);
14      error = cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
15      float msec = 0.0f;
16      error = cudaEventElapsedTime(&msec, start, stop);
17      msecTotal+=msec;
18 }
19 cout<<"Total time = "<<msecTotal<<endl;
```

To be fair,the contrast algorithm should be below:

```
1 cudaEvent_t start;
2 error = cudaEventCreate(&start);
3 cudaEvent_t stop;
4 error = cudaEventCreate(&stop);
6 float msecTotal = 0.0f;
7 int nIter = 300;
8 for (int j = 0; j < nIter; j++)
9 {
        // Record the start event    
11      error = cudaEventRecord(start, NULL);
12      matrixMulCUDA2<<< grid, threads >>>(...);
       // Record the stop event
13      error = cudaEventRecord(stop, NULL);
14      error = cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
15      float msec = 0.0f;
16      error = cudaEventElapsedTime(&msec, start, stop);
17      msecTotal+=msec;
18 }
19 cout<<"Total time = "<<msecTotal<<endl;
```

My question is that the method is right? for I am not sure.
Obviously,the time should be more longer than normal.

Answer (score 1):

You should get similar results either way.  By recording the events around the kernel launch, you are definitely measuring only the time spent in the kernel and not any time spent on the memcpy.

My only nit is that by calling cudaEventSynchronize() on every iteration of the loop, you are breaking CPU/GPU concurrency that is actually quite important to getting good performance.  If you must time each kernel invocation separately (as opposed to putting the for loop of nIter iterations around the kernel invocation as opposed to the whole operation), you might want to allocate more CUDA events.  If you go that route, you do not need 2 events per loop iteration - you need to bracket the operation with two, and record only need one CUDA event per loop iteration.  Then the time for any given kernel invocation can be computed by calling cudaEventElapsedTime() on adjacent recorded events.

To record the GPU times between N events:

`cudaEvent_t events[N+2];`

```
cudaEventRecord( events[0], NULL ); // record first event
for (j = 0; j < nIter; j++ ) {
    // invoke kernel, or do something else you want to time
    // cudaEventRecord( events[j+1], NULL );
}
cudaEventRecord( events[j], NULL );
// to compute the time taken for operation i, call:
float ms;
cudaEventElapsedTime( &ms, events[i+1], events[i] );
```

Comment: I want to compare the time between two algorithm on GPU.The general method is to execute once more after the program finished,such as 10 times, so the average value is,the method is from the project, "./NVIDIA_CUDA-5.0_Samples/C/0_Simple/matrixMul/matrixMul.cu". Upon your metioned:"you need to bracket the operation with two,and record only need one CUDA event per loop iteration.Then the time for any given kernel invocation can be computed by calling cudaEventElapsedTime() on adjacent recorded events." Could you give an example? because I could not catch your idea.Thanks!

Comment: cudaEventElapsedTime() passes back the time difference between two recorded events.

Comment: I edited the answer to make it more clear.  But for what you want to do, I don't think you need more than 2 events.

Comment: Thanks.I compared times for three methods upon "./NVIDIA_CUDA-5.0_Samples/C/0_Simple/matrixMul/matrixMul.cu", the first is 0.099ms which is my own method;the second is 0.098ms which is provided by ArchaeaSoftware; the third is 0.095ms which is original in matrixMul.cu